# Parse an entry to get a zip code

Tags: php, regex, zipcode

I have a form that someone can enter in a city and state or a zip code. I'm trying to take that entry and determine a zip code for it so I can find the surrounding zip codes. Does anyone have any good logic that they've used to do this? I'm thinking people could enter in the following entries.

- chicago, il
- chicago il
- 60601
- st. louis, mo
- st louis, mo
- st louis mo

I was thinking of using `explode` but based on the different entries I'm not sure I can do that. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Search for a 5 number digit. `preg_match("/(\d{5})/", $str, $matches);`

Comment: Ok but what if the person enters in a city instead of a zip code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easier way in my opinion would be to just use google geocoding api and get the contents of eg: http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/geo?q=st.%20louis%20mo&output=json (Seems the url has some hotlink protection of something, copy paste the link to view the actual output)

You get everything in a json format, or xml if you wish - and get all the info you need.

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/

Comment: This looks like it could work. Would I still need to store the zip codes in my database? I'm trying to select places in the area that have registered for my site so I think I would need to get the name from the json results and then look up the zip code in my database. Then in my script have something that finds all the zip codes within 15 miles of the city/zip they entered and select my users from that??

Comment: Best is to save it yes, the fewer calls you have to do to google, the better. Also since you're going to check for zip codes in a certain radius, the following links may be interesting for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1246271/finding-zip-codes-in-a-specific-radius and http://www.sanisoft.com/phpziplocator/

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a database with zip-entrys?

If you are using a database, you have to know the fields and structure to build a query - or you could use an API to get the zip-numbers.

Comment: I will have a database but will need to obviously structure my query correctly. So need to find out how to query by a city.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to explode it, replace all newlines by whitespaces, explode by whitespaces and iterate over the resulting array, comparing.

Or do as Briedis suggested.
“Search for a 5 number digit. preg_match("/(\d{5})/", $str, $matches);”

Answer (score 0):

user1048676:

How is your database of zip codes structured?

This problem may depends heavily on heuristics

ie:

```
explode("\n", "chicago, il\nchicago il\n60601\nst. louis, mo\nst louis, mo\nst louis mo");
foreach zip in zipcodes
    remove comma or any other characters
    try to parse as integer
    if parsed integer is in the range of zip codes, done
    else
        get last contentious word, and use that as the state, and the rest as the city, lookup
    endif
endforeach
```

Or use google map api to get the zip code?