# Is phpZipLocator useful? Need to get all zip codes within a given zip

Tags: php, mysql, distance, zipcode

After reading [Finding Zip Codes in a Specific Radius](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1246271/finding-zip-codes-in-a-specific-radius), I set up phpZipLocator. It is easy to use, but I don't know if it works.

There are 107 zip codes within 1 mile of 12345. That doesn't seem correct.

Does anyone know if this solution is reasonably accurate? Is the problem just with short distances?

Is there a better solution or a better way to use it (for example with a different list of zip codes)?

Need to get all zip codes within a given zip.

Working in PHP and MySQL (and Javascript, if necessary).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use http://zips.sourceforge.net. Works great for me!